# Loop or vector for creating multiple graphs for network analysis in R

Tags: r, loops, igraph, lapply, network-analysis

I've created a graph from a dataframe with igraph that shows how students move between vocational courses. The first two columns are 'From' and 'To' which contain the qualification names (vertices) with an occurrence for  each time a student enrols in a course for the first time (From) and then enrols in another (To). The remaining columns contain values relating to that particular student's demographics.

I'd like to create and plot individual networks for movements 'To' OR 'From' each individual course (788 unique courses). I can achieve this through a subgraph or filtering the original dataframe, but I think a loop or lapply function would be required so that I don't need to type the formula repeatedly. I'd also like to create a plot and PDF of each network. Unfortunately my R skills aren't good enough for me to figure out the loop/lapply part.

The first two columns of my dataframe are outlined below (I've removed student info for privacy reasons):

```
    > dput(droplevels(head(df)))
structure(list(From = structure(c(5L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("ADVANCED DIPLOMA OF ACCOUNTING", 
"ADVANCED DIPLOMA OF CONVEYANCING", "ADVANCED DIPLOMA OF LEADERSHIP AND MANAGEMENT", 
"ADVANCED DIPLOMA OF NETWORK SECURITY", "ADVANCED DIPLOMA OF POLICING", 
"ADVANCED DIPLOMA OF VISUAL ARTS"), class = "factor"), To = structure(c(5L, 
1L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("DIPLOMA OF ACCOUNTING", "DIPLOMA OF EVENT MANAGEMENT", 
"DIPLOMA OF INFORMATION TECHNOLOGY NETWORKING", "DIPLOMA OF LEADERSHIP AND MANAGEMENT", 
"DIPLOMA OF POLICING", "DIPLOMA OF VISUAL ARTS"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I then create the graph as follows

```
g <- graph_from_data_frame(df, directed = TRUE, vertices = NULL)
E(g)$weight <- 1
    g <- delete.edges(g, which(E(g)$weight <= 10)) 
g <- delete.vertices(g,which(degree(g)==0))
```

I then make the plot pretty with some colour and label changes and make a pdf as follows.

```
pdf("Qual_Pathways.pdf", width = 11.7, height = 16.5)
plot(g)
dev.off
```

How can I make it so each unique value in From or To is looped through to make a series of 788 networks that show the connections to and from that particular qualification? I'd really appreciate any help with this, I can't seem to find anything.

Comment: Check your code above -- I think there are errors in at least the first two sections that make this example not reproducible. Also, if you can explain more about this 788 networks. Is it the total number of nodes in your full dataset? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think maybe this is what you are trying to do. First, be sure to `setwd` to a directory where all the plots will be dumped into. Next, create an object to contain all of the ego graphs, that is, only the nodes that connect to a particular node:

```
library(igraph)  # you must have loaded it earlier, but just in case
z <- make_ego_graph(g)
```

This generates a list of `igraph` objects:

```
> z
[[1]]
IGRAPH 3e60c3b DNW- 4 4 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c), salary_income (e/n), other_income (e/n), survey_weights (e/n), weight
| (e/n)
+ edges from 3e60c3b (vertex names):
[1] 1->1 2->1 4->1 6->1

[[2]]
IGRAPH 3e60c3b DNW- 2 2 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c), salary_income (e/n), other_income (e/n), survey_weights (e/n), weight
| (e/n)
+ edges from 3e60c3b (vertex names):
[1] 1->1 2->1

...

[[7]]
IGRAPH 3e60c3c DNW- 3 2 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c), salary_income (e/n), other_income (e/n), survey_weights (e/n), weight 
| (e/n)
+ edges from 3e60c3c (vertex names):
[1] 3->0 5->0
```

You can dump all 7 ego networks to files like this:

```
jpeg(filename="EgoGraph%03d.jpeg")
for (i in 1:length(z)) { plot(z[[i]]) }
dev.off()
```

Now go look in the directory you `setwd` to and there will be `EgoGraph001.jpeg` through `EgoGraph007.jpeg`. If you do this with the whole dataset and it has 788 nodes it will give 788 plots in that directory.

Comment: This is great, thanks so much for this response. I’m wondering if it’s possible to name each jpeg file with the node ID aka the ‘From’ value in this scenario? Thanks again

Comment: that's an entirely different question (would recommend that you post it! would be fun to work on) & in the meantime click the option to select this as the answer so it's marked as completing your original question. thanks :)

Comment: Done and done, thanks again for your help. Here's the question regarding file names if you're interested :-) https://stackoverflow.com/q/51603769/9873574